# System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'. NET 6

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4, .net-6.0

i have implemented IdentityServer4 in .net 6 to provide authorization for my .NET 6 API's which are  working fine in my local dev environment, but am running into issues after deployed to docker using AKS cluster behind reverse proxy. I am able to generate an access token , but when I attempt to access a protected API using the token I get the following exception

> ** Exception occurred while processing message.
> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'.
> ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()

**

***my startup code***

```
   // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        base.ConfigureServices(services);

        #region Register MediatoR
        services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));
        #endregion

        services.RegisterExternalProviderIDPServices(configuration: Configuration);
        services.AddScoped<ITestRepository, TestRepository>();
        
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader();
        });

        if (Environment.IsProduction())
        {
            
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                
                context.Request.Scheme = "https";
                HostString httpsHostString = new HostString("my-api-url");
                context.Request.Host = httpsHostString;
                await next.Invoke();
            });
            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                context.Request.PathBase = "/basepath";
                return next();
            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        }
        
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
            c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API");
        });
        
        base.Configure(app, env);
    }
```